# Jquery Date picker toDateTime

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc

I am working on a project in which i am using Jquery Datepicker to select to and from date to filter records,

I have DateTime field in my Database table and on selecting date from datepicker i am doing ajax call,

the problem is arising is that in my database i have records with time(eg: 2009-08-08 13:12:23.143)
and from datepicker i am having record without time(ie 2009-08-08), I have converted it to DateTime but still i am having same record, Because of this difference my query returns null result, Can any one suggest how to handle this?
Regards

Comment: also vote up the answer, if don't mind :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use only the date part of DateTime object (if you do not want to consider time) for filter... in your where clause of query, do like this

```
where (@pDate is null  or CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), Date,111) between CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), @pStartDate,111) and CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), @pEndDate,111))
```

Comment: Thanks,it working perfectly, i've to apply between in where how can i do this in between?